# setting up remotely accessible wamp server along with iis

Tags: php, mysql, iis, windows-server-2003, wamp

I am new to Windows IIS and I need to run a php/mysql application on it. For local php development on windows, I have found WAMP to be the easiest.

But can WAMP be used in this case instead of installing php and mysql separately ?

This needs to be done on an ec2 Windows 2003 instance. So far, I have already tried installing WAMP and setting up apache to listen on port 8080 instead of 80. From inside the remote desktop, both IIS and WAMP work properly in parallel on their respective ports.

However, when I try to connect from another computer using the ip address `http://184.**.***.***`, IIS works fine serving the default web page but cannot connect to apache on `http://184.**.***.***:8080`.

Is it possible to use WAMP at all for this purpose and if yes, would there be any disadvantages in using it instead of installing php/mysql seperately ?

**Edit** :

I dont know if this is a problem of blocked 8080 port. To verify this I stopped IIS and configured apache to listen to 80. Even then `http://184.**.***.***` doent show the WAMP homepage. IS anything needed to be configured in IIS ?

### RESOLVED :

Added the port 80 in Windows Firewall Exceptions and it started working. 
Also, its necessary to select "Put Online" in the WAMP tray otherwise it gives a forbidden response as suggested by some answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used EC2 in this way before, but broadly speaking, I'd encourage you to use the same server for development and production environments if at all possible - the installation effort can be a bit of a pain, but it's nothing compared to developing an app locally and then finding an IIS configuration issue causes it to break on production. 
This approach also lets you keep your PHP configurations in source code control - php.ini and any modules you're using - and automatically deploy them alongside your application; again, forgetting to deploy the correct PHP.ini usually makes your application do crazy things...

So, your choices appear to be: 
- switch off IIS and have WAMP listen to port 80. Not sure WAMP is designed for production level traffic, but in the past, I've run low-traffic public websites in this way.
- work out why port 8080 is blocked, and if it can be unblocked. This would still require you to run your website on an unusual port, which makes for ugly and hard-to-communicate URLs.
- install PHP on your IIS instance. One benefit of having installed WAMP is that MySQL should already be up and running, and the basic PHP installation should also be there; getting PHP to run on IIS is no longer a dark art ([http://php.iis.net][1])

For my money, I'd go for the latter option...IIS is a production quality server, and it's clearly what Amazon want you to use in this instance.

Of course, running IIS on your development environment may be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now I need to get this running quickly. So will stick to WAMP for now. Will install php/mysql separately later on. Also I tried stopping IIS and making apache listen on the default port 80. But facing issues. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, there is an option "go public" (or "put online") on the system traya icon of wamp.
This option modifies the httpd.conf to authorize public access.
You should give a try.

On a side note, you can make php work with IIS. This is another option to help you manage your server. (Mysql and Php have to be installed separatly but, this is very easy to do as far as I remember :) )

Answer (score 1):

Have you put the server online? Think it is offline by default, meaning it's only accessible from your local machine. It's an option in the systray menu to put it online.

[image]

Comment: tried this too but no help.. I really wish its this simple :)

Comment: yeah, I just know that sometimes it *is* that simple. So thought I could mention it just in case :p